# 3rd monitor not detected but system "reacts" when it gets plugged in

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I recently tried adding a 3rd monitor to my machine (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS).

Right now my setup is two monitors: my laptop's built-in one (1080p) and an external 4k monitor on thunderbolt. It is set in extended display mode and with 200% zoom (else everything is way too tiny on my 4k).

Now when I plug in this new external monitor (1080p) on my only laptop HDMI, the system does register that something was plugged in: it briefly pops the "new display" choice bar: Extend display - Mirror - Single etc... And all my displays reset to 100% zoom from 200%.
So at first it seems like it does detect a new display was added, but the display stays black and does not appear in the displays part of settings.

The new display also does not appear connected when I run `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    144.03*+  60.08    60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   ...
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 525mm x 295mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+
   3360x1890     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I think my system should support 3 displays, especially since when I boot on Windows (dual boot) all 3 displays are working fine.

When I run: `xrandr --listproviders`

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

When I run: `lspci -v | grep VGA -A 10`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 173
    Memory at ab000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 40000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at ac000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at ad000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

An other weird side effect: when I disconnect the new non working display, the built-in display goes black. I then have to unplug and replug the 4k display for it to come back.

I didn't really find anyone with the same exact issue. Could it be an issue with my Nvidia driver? Any other commands / setups I could check?

Comment: Are you sure your computer can support 3 monitors at once? The issues you have tell me maybe it can not.

Comment: @smagnan please update your question with the make/model of laptop. I can see that there is no `Kernel driver in use` for the NVIDIA hardware. I am no expert here but perhaps to support 2 external monitors at once the laptop needs both the Intel integrated graphics and nvidia? I have a similar setup with 2 external monitors and mine shows `i915` drivers in use for integrated and `nouveau` for Nvidia (as I do not use Nvidia proprietary drivers). Go to Ubuntu Software Updater, click on `Settings...` and go to `Additional Drivers` tab. What does it show for `GeForce GTX 1660`?